# Replacing rope/cord/tape/slings on protection gear

Tags: gear, rock-climbing, maintenance

We all know that due to age-related deterioration, ropes, harnesses, slings and other "software" should be replaced after a certain period even if thay have not been damaged or been involved in high fall factor falls.

But what about the ropes, slings, tapes or cords attached directly to nuts, cams and other protection gear?

Even of they appear undamaged, should they also be replaced after a certain period? If they should, then how long should that period be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For cams, Black Diamond [recommends](http://blackdiamondequipment.com/en/qc-labreslinging-camalots-and-c3s.html):

- With occasional use: slings should be replaced every 5-8 years
- With frequent use: slings should be replaced 2-5 years.

This sounds like a good policy for any other soft good (from tricams to harnesses). As you mentioned, harsher use or any sign of damage can significantly reduce this time frame.

Some other resources:

- [Mountain Tools](http://www.mtntools.com/cat/rclimb/cams/mt_camresling.htm)
- [About.com](http://climbing.about.com/od/climbinggear/a/Resling-Your-Climbing-Cams.htm)
- [Yates](http://yatesgear.com/climbing/slings/index.htm) reslinging